# Clarification on understanding of linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I'm an undergraduate student. I've read Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right till chapter 5 and skimmed through Strang's Linear Algebra and It's Applications. We are taught how to solve systems of linear equations in school. Linear algebra is study of linear transformations and vector spaces which are more abstract than Linear equations. Mathematics at this level goes from learning calculations(algebra, trigonometry,calculus) to studying more general concepts(real analysis, linear algebra). Am I right?

Comment: Depends on what you classify as "abstract". If you mean Abstract algebra, then this is typically what comes after the more concrete algebra in linear algebra classes. This is the more axiomatic study of algebra.

Comment: I think it's more correct to say this is a higher level of abstract math than you've previously dealt with. For example, arithmetic operations with pure numbers is a higher level of abstraction than observing that putting $3$ marbles in a box that already has $5$ marbles in it results in a box with $8$ marbles in it (similarly, letting $3$ new cows into a field with $5$ cows already in it $\ldots).$ Also, school algebra computations such as $3x - 2$ plus $5x + 3$ is a higher level of abstraction than a pure number computation such as $3$ plus $5.$

Comment: Linear equations is an aspect of it. But I would just say, understanding how to reason about vector spaces and linear maps is essential since linear structure occurs frequently throughout mathematics. I've been thankful that I studied a bit of linear algebra many times, but almost never was that because I needed to understand a system of linear equations